# Adding CSS using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form and its attributes.Now I have to add `CSS` dynamically to each attribute html attribute like text, textarea, checkbox, dropdown.

I also have another separate block which displays possible `CSS` attributes for adding `CSS` to form like font,font-style,width,padding for each html attribute. What is the best way of adding `CSS` to form via jquery. Mere adding normal CSS jquery like,

```
$( this ).css( "color", "red" );
```

to the form creates a lot of work. Is there any plugin in jquery that supports mainly for `CSS` related tasks. Or should I go with `.css()` jquery attribute itself. I need to add `CSS` to the form via inline. I will then save it.

Comment: can we provide your form html ? or a jsfidle

Comment: I have a seperate block for adding css. That block has many input boxes with each attribute like font-style,padding,width. Each time adding css to it using .css() will take a large script.

Comment: Yeah or a small and parameterized script.

Comment: Use like this $(this).css({ "color":"red", "font":"12px","width":"100px" })

Answer (score 2):

Have you consider this approach? :

```
$(this).addClass("classname");
```

It is much easier to manage CSS tags with this rather than using `$(element).css` many times.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( this ).css( "color", "red" ). css("minWidth", "100%");
```

or

```
$( this ).css({ color : 'red', minWidth: '100' });
```

**CssObject** properties are the same as CSS properties but in camel case. Remove any `-` then transform in upper case the next letter, eg:

**CSS property**

```
border-bottom-width : 10px;
```

**JQuery CSS Object Property**

```
borderBottomWidth : '10px'
```